# Обновление данных через Hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Я новичок в использовании `JPARepository`, столкнулся с интересным моментом. Есть сущность - класс `Users`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "my_sk_example_table")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private UserCurrentNumber obj;
}
```

как можно заметить, он содержит в себе еще один объект `UserCurrentNumber`, вот собственно он:

```
@Data
public class UserCurrentNumber {
    private int current;
}
```

В базе данных (использую `PostgreSQL`) данная таблица выглядит так:

```
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 obj    | jsonb   |           | not null |
```

Пусть в таблице лежит один объект:

```
 id |      obj
----+----------------
  1 | {"current": 0}
```

**Перейдем ближе к сути:**

Мне приходит запрос, который содержит два числа:

Первое число- `id` объекта `Users`.

Второе число - значение, которое необходимо присвоить объекту (который мы можем получить по `id` соответственно)

1. Я понимаю, что я должен для начала получить объект , используя `id` из базы данных
2. Установить ему новое значение
3. Выполнить метод `save`, который перезапишет данные в таблице.

**НО:**

Это работает не так, как мне нужно.

Если я делаю все так, как описал выше, то есть:

```
public void modify(int id, int secondParam) {
   var userById=repository.getReferenceById(id);
   userById.getObj().setSecondParam(secondParam);
   repository.save(userById);
}
```

то данные в таблице не изменяются, хотя мне кажется, что должны, ведь я записываю объект, который уже имеется в базе данных (у них совпадают `id` (`primary key`), и объект должен быть перезаписан).

Но если я делаю так:

```
var result = repository.getReferenceById(id);
        var userCurrentNumber = new UserCurrentNumber();
        userCurrentNumber.setSecondParam(secondParam);
        result.setObj(userCurrentNumber);
         repository.save(result);
```

то данные успешно обновляются.

То есть получается, что пока я не пересоздам объект (`UserCurrentNumber`), данные в таблице не обновятся.

Можете подсказать, с чем это связано?